# What is the Russian equivalent of the phrase "as in"?

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление

In English, I like to say "as in" a lot. It sounds a little less formal than "For instance" and less pretentious, and means something slightly different than "e.g." What is the general approximation of "as in" in Russian? This is the type of thing automated translators mangle horribly.

An example would be "I would like a job. As in actual employment, not a gig" or in "You are talking about Bologna? As in the city, or the delicious meat snack?"

Bonus sub-question: what category of phrases would "as in" fall under so I can research further such idioms in Russian. I am tempted to search for "rhetorical phrases" or something similar, but that hasn't gotten me quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please give some examples of this "as in".

Comment: Dictionaries will be helpful—http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=as+in&l1=1

Comment: It's not an idiom or a rhetorical phrase, it's just a phrase. :) Try this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection

Comment: Is it different semantically from "that is"?

Comment: In addition to what was suggested, you can also use "как".

Answer (score 8):

"То есть."

```
Хочу найти работу. То есть настоящую работу, не халтурку какую-нибудь.

Ты сказал "Болонья"? То есть город или мясное блюдо?
```

It is pronounced as one word with the stress on "то" and is often abbreviated to "т.е."

I would class it as a conjunction (союз).

Comment: то есть = that is.

Answer (score 8):

You should see the topic "союзы". I can suggest several suitable variants, from neutral to colloquial.

> Хочу найти работу. **Как то/То есть/а именно/в смысле** настоящую работу, не подработку на время.

**Как то, то есть, a именно,в смысле** 
Synonyms (also can be used):
   другими словами, иными словами, иначе говоря.

Answer (score 2):

In colloquial I would say "(ну) типа".

```
"You are talking about Bologna? As in the city, or the delicious meat snack?"
"Ты говоришь о Болонье? Типа, о городе или о вкусной мясной еде?"

A: Do you like chocolate?
B: Like...as in?
A: As in love.
B: Yeah, sure, I love chocolate!

A: Тебе нравится шоколад?
B: Нравится...типа как?
A: Типа любишь.
B: Да, конечно, я люблю шоколад!
```

Comment: I think that "типа" better matches the "kind of/kinda" interjection.